# How to get the related models first objects in a single query in Django?

Tags: django

```
 class Product(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="products_category", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     sku = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

 class ProductVariants(DateTimeModel):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="products_variants", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`products = Product.objects.select_related('category')`
how to get all the parent model objects with their related model's first object in a single query. `[0] and first()` is not working. how to fetch that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Product.objects.select_related("product", "product__category")
```

Could be useful for you to look at https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: `"Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'product'. Choices are: category"` If i give `Product.objects.select_related('category')` I get all the products variants with the related parent product objects. But, I need to get the first product variant object in each with each related parent object.